# how can i clone a Table Row with a keydown input using "which"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm trying to clone the last row of my table and append it to the table, with blank values, when you press tab on the last name input field. so I wrote the code below. it works great until you get to the second line, it doesn't seem to clone and append the row if it's a clone. is there a way around this / What am I doing wrong?

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $last_name = $('.last_name');
        var $blank_row = $('tr:last');
        var $time_table = $('#time_table');
        
        $last_name.keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.which === 9) {
            $blank_row.clone().find('input').val('').end().appendTo($time_table);
            }
        });                
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="time_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th class="time">ST</th>
        <th class="time">TH</th>
        <th class="time">DT</th>
        <th class="time">EX-ST</th>
        <th class="time">EX-TH</th>
        <th class="time">EX-DT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="blank_row">
        <td><input type="text" name="last_name" class="last_name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="st" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="th" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="dt" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ex_st" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ex_th" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ex_dt" class="time_input"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.last_name` is added dynamically — variable `$last_name` stores a reference to the first empty row.

https://api.jquery.com/on/

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $time_table = $('#time_table');
        
        $time_table.on('keydown', '.last_name', function(e) {
            if (e.which === 9) {
            $('tr:last').clone().find('input').val('').end().appendTo($time_table);
            }
        });                
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="time_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th class="time">ST</th>
        <th class="time">TH</th>
        <th class="time">DT</th>
        <th class="time">EX-ST</th>
        <th class="time">EX-TH</th>
        <th class="time">EX-DT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="blank_row">
        <td><input type="text" name="last_name" class="last_name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="st" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="th" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="dt" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ex_st" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ex_th" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ex_dt" class="time_input"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, thank you, .on() looks very helpful for future things.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

The `keydown()` binding you're using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach the handler to elements that already exist. It won't get bound to elements created dynamically. To do that, need to create a "delegated" binding by using `on()`.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var $last_name = 'input.last_name';
    var $blank_row = $('tr:last');
    var $time_table = $('#time_table');

    $("#time_table").on("keydown", $last_name, function (e) {
        if (e.which === 9) {
            $blank_row.clone().find('input').val('').end().appendTo($time_table);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="time_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th class="time">ST</th>
        <th class="time">TH</th>
        <th class="time">DT</th>
        <th class="time">EX-ST</th>
        <th class="time">EX-TH</th>
        <th class="time">EX-DT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="blank_row">
        <td><input type="text" name="last_name" class="last_name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="st" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="th" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="dt" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ex_st" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ex_th" class="time_input"></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ex_dt" class="time_input"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be much better to use `$("#time_table")` instead of `$("body")`. Also, instead of: *"Try this"* please elaborate what makes your code working as expected - it will help future readers.

Comment: @omi this adds a new row for every keydown of Tab regardless of where in row it happens, I just wanted it when tab was pressed on the last name input. is there a way of doing that?